# Spring boot JWT Bearer token based application, not returning any access token while login attempt via Postman

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt, bearer-token

The project has the functionality to register the user and then log in and redirecting to the page based on user role i.e. either user or admin.

For now, I am trying to make the login aspect functional only without focusing on the redirecting part.

So, when a user registration request is sent via Postman, the user details are stored in the DB and a custom message is displayed in Postman's console saying that "User Registration Successful" and the user receives an activation link via email. After clicking on that link, the account is activated and when a login attempt is done using the same username and password, instead of receiving an access-token as a response I receive an error in:

```
POSTMAN: 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    "timestamp": "2020-12-10T16:51:03.051+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/api/auth/login"
}

and in Spring suite Tool as :
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2020-12-10 11:51:03.044 ERROR 26542 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key argument cannot be null.] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key argument cannot be null.
    at io.jsonwebtoken.lang.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:82) ~[jjwt-api-0.11.2.jar:0.11.2]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.signWith(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:113) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.2.jar:0.11.2]

    at com.fdmgroup.FdmMarketplace.config.JwtProvider.generateToken(JwtProvider.java:44) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.fdmgroup.FdmMarketplace.service.UserService.login(UserService.java:114) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.fdmgroup.FdmMarketplace.service.UserService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fa847670.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:687) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at com.fdmgroup.FdmMarketplace.service.UserService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2d292917.login(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.fdmgroup.FdmMarketplace.controller.UserController.login(UserController.java:51) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:807) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at com.fdmgroup.FdmMarketplace.config.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:45) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

**JwtProvider class**

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import static io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts.parser;
import static io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts.parserBuilder;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;

import com.fdmgroup.FdmMarketplace.exception.FdmMarketException;


@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Service
public class JwtProvider {
    
//  @Autowired
    private KeyStore keyStore;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try {
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            InputStream resourceAsStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/springblog.jks");
            keyStore.load(resourceAsStream, "password".toCharArray());
        } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | IOException e) {
            throw new FdmMarketException("Exception occurred while loading keystore", e);
        }

    }

    public String generateToken(Authentication authentication) {
        User principal = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(principal.getUsername())
                .signWith(getPrivateKey())
                .compact();
    }
    
    private PrivateKey getPrivateKey() {
        try {
            return (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey("springblog", "password".toCharArray());
        } catch (KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
            throw new FdmMarketException("Exception occured while retrieving public key from keystore", e);
        }
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public boolean validateToken(String jwt) {
//      ((JwtParser) parserBuilder().setSigningKey(getPublickey())).parseClaimsJws(jwt);
        parser().setSigningKey(getPublickey()).parseClaimsJws(jwt);
        return true;
    }

    private PublicKey getPublickey() {
        try {
            return keyStore.getCertificate("springblog").getPublicKey();
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            throw new FdmMarketException("Exception occured while " +
                    "retrieving public key from keystore", e);
        }
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public String getUsernameFromJwt(String token) {
        Claims claims = parser()
                .setSigningKey(getPublickey())
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();

        return claims.getSubject();
    }

}
```

**JwtAuthenticationFilter Class**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{
    
    @Autowired
    private JwtProvider jwtProvider;
    
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        
        String jwt = getJwtFromRequest(request);
        if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && jwtProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {
            String username = jwtProvider.getUsernameFromJwt(jwt);

            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,
                    null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String getJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7);
        }
        return bearerToken;
    }
    
    

}
```

**UserService Class**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.fdmgroup.FdmMarketplace.config.JwtProvider;
import com.fdmgroup.FdmMarketplace.dao.UserRepository;
import com.fdmgroup.FdmMarketplace.dao.VerificationTokenRepository;
import com.fdmgroup.FdmMarketplace.dto.AuthenticationResponse;
import com.fdmgroup.FdmMarketplace.dto.LoginRequest;
import com.fdmgroup.FdmMarketplace.dto.RegisterRequest;
import com.fdmgroup.FdmMarketplace.exception.FdmMarketException;
import com.fdmgroup.FdmMarketplace.model.NotificationEmail;
import com.fdmgroup.FdmMarketplace.model.User;
import com.fdmgroup.FdmMarketplace.model.VerificationToken;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class UserService {

//  @Autowired //it is better to use constructor injection over field inject(autowire).
    
    private final UserRepository repo;
    
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final VerificationTokenRepository verificationTokenRepo;
    private final MailService mailService;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final JwtProvider jwtProvider;
    
    
    @Transactional
    public void signup(RegisterRequest registerRequest) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(registerRequest.getUsername());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(registerRequest.getPassword()));
        user.setCity(registerRequest.getCity());
        user.setCountry(registerRequest.getCountry());
        user.setFirstname(registerRequest.getFirstname());
        user.setLastname(registerRequest.getLastname());
        user.setPhoneNumber(registerRequest.getPhoneNumber());
        user.setPostalCode(registerRequest.getPostalCode());
        user.setProvinceState(registerRequest.getProvinceState());
        user.setEmail(registerRequest.getEmail());
        user.setRoles(registerRequest.getRoles());
        user.setStreet(registerRequest.getStreet());
        user.setCreated(Instant.now());
        user.setEnabled(false);
        repo.save(user);
        
        log.info("User Registered Successfully, Sending Authentication Email");
        String token = generateVerificationToken(user);
        mailService.sendMail(new NotificationEmail("Please Activate your Account",
                user.getEmail(), "Thank you for signing up to FDM Marketplace, " +
                "please click on the below url to activate your account : " +
                "http://localhost:8080/api/auth/accountVerification/" + token));
    }
    
    
    //when a user signs up, he will get a verification email with a token, which he must click to verify his account, when he does that the Enabled 
    //field above will be set to True
    
    //randomUUID generates unique and random 128 bit value, this token must be saved in the database as well, and not in memory just in case
    //a user forgets to validate right away
    
    public String generateVerificationToken(User user) {
        String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        VerificationToken verificationToken = new VerificationToken();
        verificationToken.setToken(token);
        verificationToken.setUser(user);
        
        verificationTokenRepo.save(verificationToken);
        return token;
        
    }


    public void verifyAccount(String token) {
        Optional<VerificationToken> verificationToken = verificationTokenRepo.findByToken(token);
        verificationToken.orElseThrow(() -> new FdmMarketException("invalid Token"));
        fetchUserandEnable(verificationToken.get());
        }

    @Transactional
    private void fetchUserandEnable(VerificationToken verificationToken) {
        String username = verificationToken.getUser().getUsername();
        User user  = repo.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(() -> new FdmMarketException("Username not Found - " + username));
        user.setEnabled(true);
        repo.save(user);
    }


    public AuthenticationResponse login(LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        Authentication authenticate = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), 
                loginRequest.getPassword()));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticate); //to check if a user is loggedin already
        String token = jwtProvider.generateToken(authenticate); //we have to send this token back to the user, so we create Authenticationresponse class in dto package
        return new AuthenticationResponse(token, loginRequest.getUsername());
    }
}
```

**UserController Class**

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.fdmgroup.FdmMarketplace.dto.AuthenticationResponse;
import com.fdmgroup.FdmMarketplace.dto.LoginRequest;
import com.fdmgroup.FdmMarketplace.dto.RegisterRequest;
import com.fdmgroup.FdmMarketplace.service.UserService;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private final UserService service;

    
    
    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<String> signup(@RequestBody RegisterRequest registerRequest) {
        service.signup(registerRequest);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("User Registration Succesfull", 
                HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("accountVerification/{token}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> verifyAccount(@PathVariable String token) {
        service.verifyAccount(token);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("User Account Activated Successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public AuthenticationResponse login(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        return service.login(loginRequest);
    }
}
```

I am a beginner in this and if you want any other classinfo let me know because  I have been stuck in this for two days now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should first allow your token filter class to skip the `api/auth/login` path and set this path as "setFilterProcessesUrl". You should add you webSecirtyConfigAdapter class here.

Comment: I added "HttpSecurity.formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/api/auth/login");" in Security configuration file. Now two things are happening:
1.  With header properties: host, User-Agent, Accept, Accept-Encoding, Connections, Connection Type turned on, I get **HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request** as a response.
2. But, with credential-length turned on in header, I am getting bad credentials as a response.

Comment: could you upload your code to github and provide the link here